# how can i fix this Variables

Tags: c#

I am a junior programmer and I think that I'm making  a stupid mistake in C#

```
    Console.WriteLine("What do you call a line of people who want to punch you?");
    string answer = ("The punch line");
    Console.ReadLine();
    if (Console.ReadLine(answer))
    {
    Console.WriteLine("correct");
    }
```

Comment: You aren't looking at what the user typed.

Answer (score 5):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input.Equals(answer))
{
    Console.WriteLine("correct");
}
```

Save the user input to a variable and compare that to the answer string.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't checking the user's input. Try this:

```
    Console.WriteLine("What do you call a line of people who want to punch you?");
    string answer = ("The punch line");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (answer.Equals(input))
    {
    Console.WriteLine("correct");
    }
```